# Editable file in Maven project

Tags: java, maven, file, web-applications

i have a fully functioning webapp built with maven. Now I want to implement a file, to which a new line is added everytime a specific method is called.

Is it possible to implement such that works all inside the war?

I have tried several different ways (FileWriter, OutputStreamWriter etc.) but nothing seemed to work (had the file placed in src/main/resources).

I am very thankful for any other suggestion how I could solve this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: war is a zip archive file with some context specific (java web application) content within it and as far as you should see it, it is sealed. Sure you could open it and ammend it but that would be extremely hard, especially that the originating code came from said war file. Just create, modify and consume a file in temporary location.

Comment: You couldn't do inside .war. Try to store data in external file and keep that file path in context.